# How to use \newcommand for \href?

Tags: hyperref, macros, conditionals

I want to format Wikipedia entries in my document in a standard way:

```
\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo}{Foo}
```

So I thought about using `\newcommand*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\WWW}[2]{\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{{#2}}{{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
\WWW{Foo}
\end{document}
```

This command should set the text `Foo` linked to the Wikipedia article and one can enter a special title. However this oesn't work. Can you see what is wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two problems.  The first is that you forgot to specify that `\WWW` takes an optional argument, for which you'd need `[2][]` rather than just `[2]` (with the second `[]` specifying the empty default); the second problem is that you need to group `\ifthenelse`, but not its arguments.  (I think the problem is that when `\ifthenelse` expands, it doesn't introduce a group, and so the wrong token is being grabbed.)  Also, on the "just my opinion" side of things, if this is just for Wikipedia links, I'd probably call it `\wiki` instead.  Anyway, putting that together yields

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\wiki}[2][]{\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#2}%
                              {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#2}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
  The Wikipedia article about \wiki[the metasyntactic variable foobar]{Foobar}
is shorter than the one about \wiki{Einstein}.
\end{document}
```

(Also, note that this doesn't necessarily play well with Wikipedia's underscore-for-space convention, though that's certainly fixable.)

---

**Edit 1:**  Actually, if you use the [xstring](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) package, it's very easy to take care of underscores automatically.  This revised command will automatically replace all spaces in its argument with underscores, so you don't have to.  If you still want a different title, you can provide it.  So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\wiki}[2][]{%
  \StrSubstitute{#2}{ }{_}[\wiki@article]%
  \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\wiki@article}%
       {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#2}{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  The Wikipedia article about \wiki[the metasyntactic variable foobar]{Foobar}
is shorter than the one about \wiki{Albert Einstein} or the one about \wiki[the
creator of \TeX]{Donald Knuth}.
\end{document}
```

renders as

> The Wikipedia article about [the metasyntactic variable foobar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) is shorter than the one about [Albert Einstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) or the one about [the creator of TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

Comment: I wanted to use a second argument to work around the underscore convention. So I can write \WWW[Foo Bar]{Foo_Bar}. Besides underscore one would have to work around several special characters (like ' in Foo's Law).

Comment: @qbi: You can actually take care of underscores automatically with the `xstring` package; see my edit.  And most other special characters aren't problematic: if you specify *e.g.* `\wiki{Boyle's law}`, then you'll get linked to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle's_law, which is a perfectly valid URL.

Comment: `xstring` seems to do exactly the job I want it to do. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Spaces aren’t a problem, Wikipedia will do the redirect automatically; no need to escape them. Proof: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle's%20law).

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
\newcommand{\WWW}[1]{%
    \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#1}{#1}%
}
```

But of course, it is not sufficient if you want to be able to specify a title... how about a second, separate command for when you want to do that?

Comment: He wants an optional text. I.e. `\WWW{Foo}` will display "Foo" and link to the wikipedia article on Foo, while `\WWW[Foo]{Bar}` will display "Foo" while linking to the Wiki entry on Bar.

Comment: Yep, I understood it as soon as I clicked, and then edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\wiki{%
        \@ifstar{\wiki@iii\wiki@ii}%
                {\wiki@iii\wiki@i}%
}
\newcommand*\wiki@iii[1]{%
        \begingroup
        \catcode`\_12
        \catcode`\%12
        #1%
}
\newcommand*\wiki@i[1]{\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#1}{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand*\wiki@ii[2]{\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#2}{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\wiki*{Foo's Bar}{Foo's_Bar}
\wiki{Foo}
\wiki*{Foo (Bar)}{Foo_%28Bar%29}
```

Here, you'd use `\wiki*` if you want to give it two arguments. An even better approach would be to read it character by character and perform replacement as needed. It'd take a bit more work though.