# Problem with use of '#' in custom \href command

Tags: hyperref

I'm having a similar problem as described here:
[How to use \newcommand for \href?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/how-to-use-newcommand-for-href)

However, I want to specify an URL with an `#` sign in it. I know that I should escape the `#` by `\#`, but as we have many links containing the `#`, it may be nice to be able to copy and paste the URL directly into the LaTeX code.

My current solution looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand*{\myhref}[2][]{\href{http://myserver/#2}%
                          {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#2}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\myhref{somewhere} % WORKS
\myhref[LINK TEXT]{somewhere} % WORKS

\myhref{somewhere\#anchor} % WORKS
\myhref[LINK TEXT]{somewhere\#anchor} % WORKS

\myhref{somewhere/#anchor} % WORKS NOT - BUT I WANT IT TO WORK !!!
\myhref[LINK TEXT]{somewhere#anchor} % WORKS NOT - BUT I WANT IT TO WORK !!!
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to automatically escape the `#` character in the argument to `\myhref`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to absorb the `#` as a "normal character"

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myhref}{\begingroup\@makeother\#\@myhref}
\newcommand*{\@myhref}[2][]{%
  \href{http://myserver/#2}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#2}{#1}}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

The package **hyperref** does a good job with these strange characters, but here the problem is that when you say `\myhref{somewhere#anchor}` the `#` has already been absorbed by TeX with category code 6, which breaks `\href`.

Here we tell LaTeX to open a group in which `#` will be considered as a normal character and only after this we absorb the arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have experimented with `\catcode'\#=\somenumber` a bit but I think I have tried to make `#` a letter (catcode 11).

Comment: @WolfgangUlmer That would break the use of `\#anchor` which would become a unique control sequence.

Comment: Yes. That has been my problem. I could make one of the two variants work but not both. Your solution works with both syntax variants.