# newcommand with \href

Tags: macros, hyperref

I'm having trouble using newcommand with the `\href`

I would like a newcommand like this:

```
\newcommand\link[2]{\href{#1}{\underline{#2}}}
```

This command works fine quite all, for exemple:

```
\link{htt://www.impa.br}{IMPA}
```

But it does not work when the URL name has code like #1. For example, it does not work in this exemple:

```
\link{http://matematica.obmep.org.br/index.php/modulo/index#1}{modules}
```

It does not work because the #1 in the URL name is used with the #1 in the newcommand.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I believe this is not a duplicate topic. 
But may be I did not understand your suggestion.
In my case, there are websides that have in your URL codes as # 1, for example:

[http://matematica.obmep.org.br/index.php/modulo/index#1]

And there are websites with simpler URL, for example:

[http://www.impa.br]


In all of my cases, I wish that the URL is send to the newcommand as a string.

Comment: You could use \edef\temp{#1}\href{\temp}

Comment: Excuse me. Unfortunately I did not understand your suggestion. Could you explain how it would look all the code so that I can pass any URL address for the newcommand? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Really this is a duplicate of [Problem with use of '#' in custom \href command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35310/15925).
But just to make it clear how to use this in your case here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\link}{\begingroup\@makeother\#\@mylink}
\newcommand*{\@mylink}[2]{\href{#1}{\underline{#2}}\endgroup} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\link{htt://www.impa.br}{IMPA} 

\link{http://matematica.obmep.org.br/index.php/modulo/index#1}{modules}

\end{document}
```

As in the other question, one defines a helper command which is called with `#` given an appropriate category code so it is no longer interpreted as a command argument.