# href: Illegal parameter number in definition of \test

Tags: hyperref, url

I tried to use the command `\href{url}{anchor text}` to link a page, but encountered the issue **Illegal parameter number in definition of \test**.

The error is likely caused by `#` in url. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     urlcolor    = blue
}
\usepackage{color}
\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Illegal parameter number in definition of \textbackslash test}

This works (without hash): \href{http://example.com/en/revision-control-software-managed-code-smartgit/131_Git}{Text 1}

This doesn't work (with hash): %\href{http://example.com/en/revision-control-software-managed-code-smartgit/#131_Git}{Text 1}

Error case 2: %\href{https://example.com/search?q=user%3A3067748+github}{Text 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How do I slove this problem?

Comment: You can use `\#` instead of `#` in the url. If you have several urls with a # in it and you want a more automated solution, you might find some inspiration here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35310/134144

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the commands in a frame. As they do catcode magic you must use the option `fragile`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     urlcolor    = blue
}
\usepackage{color}
\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Illegal parameter number in definition of \textbackslash test}

This works (without hash): \href{http://example.com/en/revision-control-software-managed-code-smartgit/131_Git}{Text 1}

This works (with hash): \href{http://example.com/en/revision-control-software-managed-code-smartgit/#131_Git}{Text 1}

This works: \href{https://example.com/search?q=user%3A3067748+github}{Text 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]