# Defining Macro With URL as Argument

Tags: hyperref, url

I want to define something like

```
\newcommand{\myhref}[2]{\href{#1}{do something with #1}}
```

and then paste URLs from the web into `\myhref{...}{hello}`.

The special characters in URLs mean that this works only if I fix up every URL (usually by preceding special characters with a \ ).  It would be much more pleasant if I could tell `myhref` to inherit the rules of treating urls in argument #1 just-as-if-pass-verbatim from/to `href`.

the question is closely related to [Problem with use of '#' in custom \href command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35310/problem-with-use-of-in-custom-href-command) .  However, I need a more general solution.  Unfortunately, URLs cannot just contain # , but _ and & and probably a few more special characters.  Is there a more general solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myurl}{\hyper@normalise\myurl@}
\def\myurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{See also: \textbf{#1}}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\myurl{https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+tuburl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ulrike---can you please give a macro example with two arguments, in which only one argument is the robust URL?

Comment: Your snippet didn't make use of the second argument, but the inner command can have a second argument.